# Quantifying over all random variables

Tags: probability-theory, logic

I often encounter statements in the literature in probability theory of the form:

"Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, P)$ be a probability space, $S$ a state space and $X : \Omega \to S$ a random variable with some properties ... .
Then there is a random variable $Y$ equivalent to $X$ in distribution if and only if the probabilistic property $\phi$ of $X$ is true."

This statement says that one can choose a random variable $Y$ with some special *functional* properties beside the purely probabilistic properties given by the distribution of $X$ (resp. $Y$).

The problem here is, that in this statement, there is a quantification over all random variables, which to my opinion do not form a set. The underlying probability space for the choice of $Y$ is not specified. One can only speak of equivalence in distribution if two random variables $X$ and $Y$ together with their probability spaces $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, P)$ and $(\Omega', \mathscr{A}', P')$ are already given (wherever they come from) and it holds that $P \circ X^{-1} = P' \circ Y^{-1}$. In fact, in order to be precise, a random variable $X$ is the complete tuple $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, P, X)$ and not only the function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

So, how should those statements be interpreted?
I think, the meaning of these statements is that the definition of the random variable $Y$ with the desired properties can be done *explicitely*. So, the statement should read as:

"Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, P)$ be a probability space and $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable with some properties ... .
(1) If $X$ satisfies $\phi$ then define $(\Omega', \mathscr{A}', P')$ by ... and $Y : \Omega' \to S$ by ...  and it holds that $Y$ is equivalent in distribution to $X$.

(2) Let $(\Omega', \mathscr{A}', P')$ be given and $Y : \Omega' \to S$ a random variable equivalent in distribution to $X$. Then $X$ satisfies some probabilistic property (which in turn is also satisfied by $Y$ since the property is of probabilistic nature and thus based on the distribution).

How would you interprete such statements?

Comment: You spotted well a possible lack of formality, however here it is important to know what are examples of the statements that you mean. Sometimes, one just say that there exists a random variable with a given distribution: then the probability space does not matter, however in some of the statements it is crucial that such a random variable can be constructed on the same probability space. Hence, couple of examples from your side would be of help.

Comment: Let $|S| \geq 2$ and $X : \Omega \to S^{[0, 1]}$ a stochastic process with measurable sample paths. Then there is a process $Y : \Omega' \to S^{[0,1]}$ equivalent to $X$ in distribution with non-measurable sample paths.

Comment: well, in this case you see exactly that $Y$ can be defined on a different probability space, so I am not sure where the confusion is coming from in this example

Comment: Ok, I rephrase the statement: "... Then there is random variable $Y$ defined on some probability space $\Omega'$ ..." So it is about existence of a probability space. In fact, in this example, it is possible to choose $\Omega' \subseteq S^{[0,1]}$. But as stated previously, it is a quantification over all probability spaces.

Comment: I see your point. Most of the statements of that kind (and all that I've seen) shall be indeed interpreted as we can construct a probability space, and a map with desired properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tis true, that the collection of all random variables is not a set. Because the collection of "state spaces" is not a set.

But this is now a statement in the language of set theory. It's a quantification over the universe of sets, and now it's fine. Like saying that "For every set $x$, $x\notin y$" or "For every set $x$, $|x|<|\mathcal P(x)|$" are quantifications over all sets.

The statement, when translated to the language of set theory says that whenever you have a set which satisfies the properties of being a state space, and so on and so forth, is a very complicated statement in the language of set theory, but it can be written nonetheless.

(Here is a similar example, taken from a course I am currently attending: If $X$ is a Polish space, $A\subseteq X$ is *Universally Baire* if for every topological space $Y$ and a continuous function $f\colon Y\to X$, $f^{-1}(A)$ has the Baire property in $Y$. Here we quantify over all topological spaces and continuous functions into $X$, and that's a legitimate statement about sets, so we can do it as a statement about the universe of sets.)

Comment: So, this kind of "problems" also appear when dealing with the definition of an analytic set, i.e. a continuous image of a Borel set into a Polish space. In case of probability theory, I then have to work with something like a "universe of probability spaces"? This kind of object must then be axiomaticaly defined and I hope I can work with it without running into paradoxical situations.

Comment: Well, you can just work, as you did before, implicitly, in the universe of sets. And it's fine. If you want to take a more categorical approach, then you work in some category and you make certain statements about the structure of the category, or some objects in it. In the case of analytic sets, and Polish spaces, the solution is easy. Since every Polish space has size $\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ you can bound them all, up to isometry, in a set; moreover the Borel structure of all uncountable Polish spaces is the same, so you can just pick one representative for that.

Comment: Regarding your first statement: the state space is fixed here, so apparently @yadaddy meant the collection of all random variables with a given state space.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's the same story, though.